# What are the security risks associated with a Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, template, php-7, query

What are the security risks associated with a Magento 2 website, and how can you mitigate them?

Answer (score 0):

Magento is providing its own Magento Security Patches:

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4426353041293-Security-updates-available-for-Adobe-Commerce-APSB22-12

https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-12.html